# GitLab returns various fatal errors

Tags: git, ssh, rsa, gitlab

I've had several issues with Git and SSH lately, including `git pull` not working. I'm using the same GitLab server as colleagues, but I'm having problems they've never experienced.

When I type `git pull` I get

> **fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: gitl**

**I have verified with a colleague that git remote is properly set.**

As the problem occurs only on this computer, I am also pretty sure the problem is local on this computer.

What I do know is that this works properly:

```
$ ssh -Tv -p 22 gitlab@svn.faktab.net
OpenSSH_7.1p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to svn.faktab.net [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/bls/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/bls/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/bls/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/bls/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/bls/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/bls/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/bls/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/bls/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000000
debug1: Authenticating to svn.faktab.net:22 as 'gitlab'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr umac-64@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr umac-64@openssh.com none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<3072<8192) sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:FTlgQR6hN/JPOGtpLA/bRwg0cwyYtWC8QCSf4jQA5O0
debug1: Host 'svn.faktab.net' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/bls/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /c/Users/bls/.ssh/y
debug1: Remote: Forced command: /var/gitlab/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-shell key-128
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 535
debug1: Remote: Forced command: /var/gitlab/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-shell key-128
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to svn.faktab.net ([xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
Welcome to GitLab, X X!
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 4304, received 3696 bytes, in 0.1 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 29078.1, received 24970.4
debug1: Exit status 0
```

Why can't I get `git pull` to work properly?

Comment: do you have a firewall? It allows ssh connection to/from outside?

Comment: I suppose I would not be able to do `ssh -Tv -p 22 gitlab@svn.faktab.net` if I was not able to do ssh connection?

Comment: Check your router configuration or ask to your network administrator

Comment: Well it's working for everyone else around me, and it used to work on a different computer - which stopped working completely. So I'm certain the problem has to do with this specific computer.

Comment: If available, try to clone the repository using https instead that ssh and check if that works.

Comment: `$ git clone https://svn.faktab.net:pospayclient/api.git`
`Cloning into 'api'...`
`fatal: unable to access 'https://svn.faktab.net:pospayclient/api.git/': Failed to connect to svn.faktab.net port 443: Connection refused`

Comment: It seems to me definitely a network problem.

Comment: Could be, but then it would likely be caused by some network issues -on the computer-. Networks is not my strength, so I don't know much about troubleshooting it

Comment: As I've said before, ask to your network administrator. I don't know your network/computer/server settings.

Comment: I found out that the GitLab server does not have port 443 open. That means my colleagues can't be using that port to connect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of trail and error I got things working

- Uninstall Putty
- Uninstall Git
- Delete projects
- Restart computer
- Reinstall Git
- Create new SSH key and add to GitLab profile
- Clone all projects again

Answer (score 1):

Why not copy the ssh url from the projects main page ?

It will probably be: `gitlab@svn.faktab.net/pospayclient/api.git`

So without the `ssh://`.

Comment: That gives me fatal: `'gitlab@svn.faktab.net/pospayclient/api.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.`